# How to add 2 data binding to one activity

Tags: android

I am using Drawer in my app and this drawer is inside of the drawer_layout. I called that drawer on my activity_main.xml as

```html
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:background="@color/munevo_orange">

  <include layout="@layout/fragment_drawer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since I am using the data binding, in my MainActivity.java I used data binding like that.

```html
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);
```

The problem is, I also need to bind the drawer, however, it is in the different xml file and I cannot reach it. Can I call 2 data binding or is there easier way to do it?

ps: My xml file big enough, so I wanted to split the drawer into another xml file.

Comment: I think you use 2 `data binding` you should use `data binding` in your `include`  `tag`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is the correct way. @miladsalimi

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/munevo_orange">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_drawer"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Solved the problem. The usage in the MainActivity is :

```
binding.fragment_drawer.buttonX.setText()
```

credits : @miladsalimi